# Image of circle under fractional linear transform increases in radius

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $\alpha,r\in\mathbb{R}$ with $r>0$ and $|\alpha|+r\le 1$, and consider the fractional linear transform
$$ f(z) = \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\alpha z}. $$
I would like to show the following: the circle in $C(\alpha,r)\subset\mathbb{C}$ centered at $\alpha$ with radius $r$ is mapped onto a circle of larger radius by $f$.

---

My approach: Note that $f$ maps $[-1,1]$ into $[-1,1]$ with $f(-1)=-1$ and $f(1)=1$, and in particular it maps the line segment $[\alpha-r,\alpha+r]$ to some line segment $[f(\alpha-r),f(\alpha+r)]$ on the real line. Furthermore, the line segment $[\alpha-r,\alpha+r]$ is perpendicular to the boundary of $C(\alpha,r)$ at the intersection points $\alpha\pm r$, and since conformal maps preserve angles, the image of the line segment is also perpendicular to the boundary of $f(C(\alpha,r))$ at $f(\alpha\pm r)$. Thus, $[f(\alpha-r),f(\alpha+r)]$ is a diameter of the image of $f(C(\alpha,r))$, and so if $r'$ is the radius of the $f(C(\alpha,r))$, then $2r' = f(\alpha+r)-f(\alpha-r)$. Thus, we have
\begin{align} r' = \frac{1}{2}(f(\alpha+r)-f(\alpha-r)) &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\alpha+r-\alpha}{1-\alpha(\alpha+r)}-\frac{\alpha-r-\alpha}{1-\alpha(\alpha-r)}\right) \\
&=\frac{r}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2-\alpha r}+\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2+\alpha r}\right) \\
&=r\left(\frac{(1-\alpha^2)}{(1-\alpha^2)^2-(\alpha r)^2}\right)
\end{align}
and hence
$$\frac{r}{r'} = \frac{(1-\alpha^2)^2-(\alpha r)^2}{1-\alpha^2}\le\frac{(1-\alpha^2)^2}{1-\alpha^2}\le 1\implies r'\ge r.$$

---

I would like to know if there is a simpler approach to show that the radius increases (since right now it appears just to be algebra magic), or if there is a non-rigorous but intuitive explanation for this effect. In particular, I'm wondering if this has anything to do with hyperbolic distances, given that hyperbolic distances are larger with respect to Euclidean ones near the boundary of the unit disk and smaller near the center.

Comment: +1, I think this is a very nice question. I have no idea if it will work, but perhaps the decomposition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Decomposition_and_elementary_properties) will be helpful: Two of the factors are translations, which won't affect radii. I'm not sure about the others, if they can "easily"/intuitively be seen to increase radii.

Comment: Are you sure this result is true? A small manipulation using the triangle inequality immediately yields a contradiction.

Comment: @user338102 You're free to check my work if you'd like. What is the triangle inequality manipulation you speak of?

Comment: @JoeyZou Ah sorry never mind, I realized the flaw in my argument.

Comment: When you meet the hyperbolic distance on the unit disk, it will become clear. $f$ is an automorphism of the unit disk, hence it preserves hyperbolic distances. Euclidean circles in the unit disk are also hyperbolic circles, but unless the centre is the origin, the Euclidean centre and the hyperbolic centre are different. Since $f$ preserves hyperbolic distances, $f(C(\alpha,r))$ is - for $\lvert\alpha\rvert + r < 1$, we need a limit consideration otherwise - a circle with the same hyperbolic radius as $C(\alpha,r)$. But $f$ moves the hyperbolic centre closer to the origin,

Comment: where the ratio $\dfrac{ \text{hyperbolic distance}}{\text{Euclidean distance}}$ is smaller. Hence we need a larger Euclidean distance to cover the same hyperbolic distance than in the original location.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you so much for your comments--they provided the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We can happily decompose $f$ as follows:$$f(z) = {{z - \alpha}\over{1 - \alpha z}} = {{-1}\over\alpha} + {{1 - {1\over{\alpha^2}}}\over{z - {1\over\alpha}}}.$$If$$g(z) = z - {1\over\alpha}, \quad h(z) = \left(1 - {1\over{\alpha^2}}\right)z, \quad i(z) = {1\over z},$$we have$$f(z) = g\left({{1 - {1\over{\alpha^2}}}\over{z - {1\over\alpha}}}\right) = g \circ h\left({1\over{z - {1\over\alpha}}}\right) = g \circ h \circ i \circ g(z).$$$g$ has no effect on radii, $h$ which change radii by a factor of $|1 - 1/\alpha^2|$. But the effect of $i$ on radii is essentially working through the above approach of calculating $(1/2)(f(\alpha + r) - f(\alpha - r))$, just with $f$ replaced with $i \circ g$. So to be honest, I do not think the above "algebra magic" is in any way magic, but more the actual reason as to the truth.

The question itself is not particularly deep, so it is not hugely surprising to me that the solution did not require anything deep.